# Python error in Console but not in File: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, console

I've got a Python script which has a class defined with this method:

```
@staticmethod
def _sanitized_test_name(orig_name):
    return re.sub(r'[`‘’\"]*', '', re.sub(r'[\r\n\/\:\?\<\>\|\*\%]*', '', orig_name.encode('utf-8')))
```

I'm able to run the script from the command prompt just fine, without any issues. But when I paste the code of the full class in the console, I get the `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`:

```
>>> return re.sub(r'[`‘’\"]*', '', re.sub(r'[\r\n\/\:\?\<\>\|\*\%]*', '', orig_name.encode('utf-8')))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    return re.sub(r'[``'\"]*', '', re.sub(r'[\r\n\/\:\?\<\>\|\*\%]*', '', orig_name.encode('utf-8')))
                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

If I skip that method while pasting, it works. Note that there is a difference in what my original line is and what's shown for the error: `` r'[`‘’\"]*' `` vs ``` r'[``'"]*' ```. Replacing that with `` ur'[`‘’"]*' `` gives `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`.

It seems the Python console is seeing `‘` that as a stylised `` ` `` (backtick) and the `’` as a sytlised `'` (single quote). When I really mean the [unicode open and close quotes](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html). I've got `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of my script, which I paste into the console as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on just the expression causing the error `` r'[`‘’"]*' ``...

```
>>> r'[`‘’"]*'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    r'[``'"]*'
             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> ur'[`‘’"]*'  # with the unicode modifier
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ur'[``'"]*'
              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

If the terminal I'm in doesn't accept unicode input, that interpretation of the unicode chars from `‘` to `` ` `` and `’` to `'`, occurs.

So the workaround is to split the regex and **use [`unichr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr)** with the corresponding codes for the two quotes, 2018 and 2019:

```
>>> r'[`' + unichr(2018) + unichr(2019) + r'"]*'
u'[`\u07e2\u07e3"]*'
```

(And the raw string modifier `r''` probably isn't required for this particular regex.)